# Add 5.30 Hours with selected date time in angular js within angular js date attributes side

Tags: angularjs, datetime, datepicker

I have created angular js date picker which picks up the date time but on server side shown as 5 hours 30 minutes lesser than the selected datetime. I need to fix this on angular js side.How to achieve this fix?

I have created code for this upto now:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"
       datepicker-popup="{{schedule.Date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}"
       name="Date" ng-model="schedule.Date" is-open="opened"
       datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true"
       close-text="Close" />
```

Comment: Your client and server are in different timezones due to which this is happening. Check above question.

Comment: Bro I'm checking in my local pc not any servers.I know about Time zones might be  causing the error.How to fix this?

Comment: Did you check the question I mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: Should your client not be displaying the date appropriate for who's viewing it? Why would the user care what time it was for the server, they dont even know where the server is ...

Comment: Yes bro.They suggests to fix it in server side but I need to fix it using angular js attributes alone.How could I achieve this bro?

Comment: Is your server storing ALL dates in the +5:30 timezone? Or what's the point of converting the client-side date in a specific timezone? Your server should store agnostic dates which your client can interpret. The server getting the Date  -5:30 is correct because server shouldnt have timezones.

Comment: I agree with you.For +5:30 need to add,do I should done on Scripting or server side? can't be done the same with in attribute of date-picker?